# start gerrit failed after I migrated H2 to postgresql because schema version downgrade is not supported

Tags: gerrit

I create a new gerrit (version: 2.13.11) using postgresql database, then I successfully migrated the H2 datas of my old gerrit (version: 2.13.11) to the new gerrit.  I also  executed the reindex  command. but when I try to start gerrit, it failed.
This is the detail in error_log:

[2018-05-17 15:19:10,550] [main] WARN  com.google.gerrit.server.config.GitwebCgiConfig : gitweb not installed (no /usr/lib/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi found)
[2018-05-17 15:19:10,740] [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log : Logging initialized @5032ms
[2018-05-17 15:19:10,783] [main] INFO  com.google.gerrit.server.git.LocalDiskRepositoryManager : Defaulting core.streamFileThreshold to 438m
[2018-05-17 15:19:10,797] [main] ERROR com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Unable to start daemon
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Unsupported schema version 161; expected schema version 129. Downgrade is not supported.

1 error
    at com.google.gerrit.server.schema.SchemaVersionCheck.start(SchemaVersionCheck.java:68)
    at com.google.gerrit.lifecycle.LifecycleManager.start(LifecycleManager.java:89)
    at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:313)
    at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.run(Daemon.java:214)
    at com.google.gerrit.pgm.util.AbstractProgram.main(AbstractProgram.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.invokeProgram(GerritLauncher.java:163)
    at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.mainImpl(GerritLauncher.java:104)
    at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.main(GerritLauncher.java:59)
    at Main.main(Main.java:25)

The both gerrit servers are running in jre7. I've no idea what should I do. 
Could please give me some advice? Thank you very much!

Comment: You wrote the same version for both new and old Gerrit: "new gerrit (version: 2.13.11)" and "old gerrit (version: 2.13.11). Please correct it accordingly.

Comment: It's not clear what's your situation, please add the commands you have used to "migrated the H2 data".

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my commands to export data from H2 database:**

```
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNTS', 'SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_EXTERNAL_IDS', 'SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_EXTERNAL_IDS');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_GROUPS', 'SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_GROUPS');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_GROUP_BY_ID', 'SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_GROUP_BY_ID');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_GROUP_BY_ID_AUD', 'SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_GROUP_BY_ID_AUD');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_GROUP_MEMBERS', 'SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_GROUP_MEMBERS');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_GROUP_MEMBERS_AUDIT', 'SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_GROUP_MEMBERS_AUDIT');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_GROUP_NAMES', 'SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_GROUP_NAMES');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_PROJECT_WATCHES', 'SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_PROJECT_WATCHES');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/CHANGES', 'SELECT * FROM CHANGES');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/CHANGE_MESSAGES', 'SELECT * FROM CHANGE_MESSAGES');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/PATCH_COMMENTS', 'SELECT * FROM PATCH_COMMENTS');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/PATCH_SETS', 'SELECT * FROM PATCH_SETS');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/PATCH_SET_APPROVALS', 'SELECT * FROM PATCH_SET_APPROVALS');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/SCHEMA_VERSION', 'SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_VERSION');
CALL CSVWRITE('/home/sarah/migrate213/SYSTEM_CONFIG', 'SELECT * FROM SYSTEM_CONFIG');

SELECT currval('change_message_id');
SELECT currval('change_id');
SELECT currval('account_id');
SELECT currval('account_group_id');
```

**This my commands to import the above data of old gerrit to PostgreSQL database of new gerrit:**

```
DELETE FROM ACCOUNTS;
COPY ACCOUNTS(registered_on,full_name,preferred_email,inactive,account_id) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNTS' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM ACCOUNT_EXTERNAL_IDS;
COPY ACCOUNT_EXTERNAL_IDS(account_id,email_address,password,external_id) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_EXTERNAL_IDS' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM ACCOUNT_GROUPS;
COPY ACCOUNT_GROUPS(name,description,visible_to_all,group_uuid,owner_group_uuid,group_id) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_GROUPS' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM ACCOUNT_GROUP_BY_ID;
COPY ACCOUNT_GROUP_BY_ID(group_id,include_uuid) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_GROUP_BY_ID' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM ACCOUNT_GROUP_BY_ID_AUD;
COPY ACCOUNT_GROUP_BY_ID_AUD(added_by,removed_by,removed_on,group_id,include_uuid,added_on) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_GROUP_BY_ID_AUD' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM ACCOUNT_GROUP_MEMBERS;
COPY ACCOUNT_GROUP_MEMBERS(account_id,group_id) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_GROUP_MEMBERS' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM ACCOUNT_GROUP_MEMBERS_AUDIT;
COPY ACCOUNT_GROUP_MEMBERS_AUDIT(added_by,removed_by,removed_on,account_id,group_id,added_on) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_GROUP_MEMBERS_AUDIT' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM ACCOUNT_GROUP_NAMES;
COPY ACCOUNT_GROUP_NAMES(group_id,name) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_GROUP_NAMES' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM ACCOUNT_PROJECT_WATCHES;
COPY ACCOUNT_PROJECT_WATCHES(notify_new_changes,notify_all_comments,notify_submitted_changes,notify_new_patch_sets,notify_abandoned_changes,account_id,project_name,filter) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/ACCOUNT_PROJECT_WATCHES' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM CHANGES;
COPY CHANGES(change_key,created_on,last_updated_on,owner_account_id,dest_project_name,dest_branch_name,status,current_patch_set_id,subject,topic,row_version,change_id,original_subject,submission_id,note_db_state) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/CHANGES' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM CHANGE_MESSAGES;
COPY CHANGE_MESSAGES(author_id,written_on,message,patchset_change_id,patchset_patch_set_id,change_id,uuid,tag) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/CHANGE_MESSAGES' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM PATCH_COMMENTS;
COPY PATCH_COMMENTS(line_nbr,author_id,written_on,status,side,message,parent_uuid,range_start_line,range_start_character,range_end_line,range_end_character,change_id,patch_set_id,file_name,uuid,tag) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/PATCH_COMMENTS' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM PATCH_SETS;
COPY PATCH_SETS(revision,uploader_account_id,created_on,draft,change_id,patch_set_id,groups,push_certificate) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/PATCH_SETS' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM PATCH_SET_APPROVALS;
COPY PATCH_SET_APPROVALS(value,granted,change_id,patch_set_id,account_id,category_id,tag) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/PATCH_SET_APPROVALS' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM SCHEMA_VERSION;
COPY SCHEMA_VERSION(version_nbr,singleton) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate215/SCHEMA_VERSION' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

DELETE FROM SYSTEM_CONFIG;
COPY SYSTEM_CONFIG(register_email_private_key,site_path,admin_group_id,anonymous_group_id,registered_group_id,wild_project_name,batch_users_group_id,owner_group_id,admin_group_uuid,batch_users_group_uuid,singleton) FROM '/home/sarah/migrate213/SYSTEM_CONFIG' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;


SELECT setval('change_message_id', 1);
SELECT setval('change_id', 2);
SELECT setval('account_id', 1000001);
SELECT setval('account_group_id', 2);
```

**I also have copied the git directory of old gerrit to the new gerrit.**
and I did reindex successfully.

But it failed when I executed this command: bin/gerrit.sh start